# Drush affected by El Capitan?

Tags: drush

After updating my Mac from Yosemite to El Capitan, I am noticing drush does not run properly on any of my sites. Doing a simple:

```
drush status-report

Command core-requirements needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you[error]
will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment
to run this command.
The drush command 'status-report' could not be executed.             [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
  * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
  * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
```

This is now happening on all my Drupal sites locally, and yes, I am at the root of the Drupal install directory where this command would normally work. I've updated Composer and made sure that stable Drush 7.0.0 is running. Has anyone else come across this behaviour?

Fortunately, I made a full bootable backup of Yosemite so I will 'simply' roll my Mac back to how it was setup prior to the so-called upgrade of El Capitan. Normally I wait at least a month or two before upgrading to Apple's latest release but I got reckless and now this is the price. Sometimes I just want to switch to Ubuntu full time and say goodbye to the Mac OS.

Using:

- Mac OS 10.11
- MAMP PRO 3.2.1
- Little Snitch 3.6 (mentioning this because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345132/did-el-capitan-dp8-break-connections-to-localhost-in-mamp-pro-3-4) thread)
- Composer version 1.0-dev
- Drush 7.0.0

**2015-10-17 - Update #################################**

First off, thank you for the folks who commented on the original issue. I have decided for better or worse to try again. I updated Yosemite, where Drush, Mamp and everything was working fine, to El Capitan.

I removed drush by editing the .json file for composer by removing the lines for drush and then running `composer global update` which then finished the job by removing the actual drush files. Composer is up to date, and then drush7 was installed successfully with

`composer global require drush/drush:7.0.0`

However, once I navigate to a directory with a Drupal install, I am told after running some commands that 'No drupal site was found' and yet, the commands seem to complete regardless. Here are some examples:

`drush cron` results in the following:

```
 No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.                       
 'all' cache was cleared.
```

`drush updb` results in the following:

```
 No database updates required     
 No Drupal site found, only 'drush' cache was cleared.                       
 'all' cache was cleared.
```

`drush dl hacked` results in the following:

```
 Project hacked (7.x-2.0-beta5) downloaded to
 /Users/[me]/Sites/[path]/drupal/sites/all/modules/contrib/hacked
```

Note there was no 'drupal not found' message on the last command. So, my concern is why the 'No Drupal site found' message is showing up. Here is what my .bash_profile looks like:

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.42/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

export DRUSH_PHP='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.42/bin/php'

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

None of these settings were changed from how it was in Yosemite. If anyone can shed some light on these issues, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: How did you install Drush in the first place? Homebrew? Tarball? Do your sites work at all?

Comment: Drush was installed with Composer. All of my sites worked just fine, and drush worked on every one of them. I have since reverted back to Yosemite and everything is working perfectly but I'm interested to learn if anyone else has encountered this issue. It may have to do with El Capitan's System Integrity Protection

Comment: More likely some system paths got overwritten.

Comment: Yes, or previously created directories within one or more of the disallowed place, such as /System, /bin, /usr (but not /usr/local), and /sbin no longer have permission to run. I have read that some folks had success with using symlinks. I will stay with Yosemite for a bit longer until I have time to devote to updating both the operating system and the broken applications.

Comment: Yupp, I think I'll wait too. During past OSX upgrades I also did it like you WITHOUT having created a backup before. Then I always ended up completely reinstalling my whole system. Which was a big pain while being in a hurry with running projects. But still, a fresh install maybe was the better choice after all.

Comment: FWIW, I upgraded to El Capitan last week and so far everything (including Drush) works perfectly. You (arguably) shouldn't have stuff in system folders anyway, so forcing that correction isn't a terrible thing. `/usr/local` can still be written to, that was always the best place to put this stuff anyway

Comment: @PWM Check `drush status` it-self (with `-v` and `-d`), not `status-report`. It'll show you at which points it fails (whether it's database issue or bootstrap files).

Comment: @kenorb - thanks for your comment. `drush status-report` gives you the details of what you'd see on the screen of the same name in a Drupal install, while `drush status` is about drush itself. At the moment, I'm still using Yosemite so both commands are working fine but I do recall they - and all drush commands - were failing. I think that aliases might do the trick when I eventually go back to using El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

#### Homebrew

Install Drush by Homebrew:

```
brew install drush
```

#### via Phar binary

```
sudo wget -O /usr/local/bin/drush http://files.drush.org/drush.phar
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .bash_profile file (found here: ~/.bash_profile)

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/drush:$PATH"
```

If you already have an 'export PATH=", add it like this (colon separated):

```
export PATH="/other/path:/usr/local/lib/drush:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. Drush was installed with Composer however, so my PATH is `~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer! I added `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:` to my PATH, so that it went from this:

```
    export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.42/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

To this:

```
    export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.42/bin:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
```

And now I am *not* getting any messages about 'No Drupal site found'. Hope this helps out others.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, you may also [install `drush`](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/#install-a-global-drush-via-composer) via:

```
COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/usr/local/bin composer global require drush/drush:7
```

which would automatically install `drush` binary into `/usr/local/bin`, so you don't have to add `vendor/bin` dir into your `PATH`.

However still you need to add path to your `php` binary.

If you've installed `php` via `brew`, add this line into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
which brew && brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56 > /dev/null && export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bin:$PATH"
```

However since you're using MAMP, this can help:

```
PHP_VER="5.4.42"
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php$PHP_VER/bin"
```

Then make sure you configured your mysql socket correctly by linking into it:

```
ln -vs /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

or adding into your `php.ini` (`pdo_mysql.default_socket`) or in `settings.php` (`unix_socket`).

Answer (score 0):

$ brew install homebrew/php/drush

this worked for me, on MacBook Pro - mama - el capitan
I installed brew first, then the above command which installed composer as well.